# Is it possible to add functions to the ribbon in File Explorer (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

The Ribbon in Windows's File Explorer is the tab-filled menu on top of the folder. It has some useful fonctions, and is contextual (images options, video options, trashbin options,...).

There is a lot of empty space in the Ribbon.

**Is it possible to add functions, or create a custom Ribbon, in Windows 10?**

For example, I have a Python program that creates square versions of all pictures in the folder it is located. I can copy and run the file in all folders where I need to square photos, but I think it would be convenient to have access to this function in every folder with pictures simply by a clic on the ribbon.

Is it doable?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: @harrymc: could you expand on this?

Comment: I dont really understand the reason for the VTC. I would be OK if it was off-topic, but "need more focus (asking more than one question)" does not make sense here.

Comment: There is no way to modify the user interface of Explorer. Only Microsoft can.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/developing-with-windows-explorer

For a developer you may be able to use the provided APIs in Windows to hook into the Explorer UI and add tabs and buttons. It is not going to be a simple process though.